# Header is not working with additional_headers

Tags: php

```
mail("@.com", "Thank you for your purchased!",$customer_msg,"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
```

The above mail function works fine, however if i add

```
 $header = "From: @.com"
```

then the additional_header (Content-Type) gets ignore and the css/HTML styling for my email becomes just plain text. I have added the $headers before and after the additional_headers but nothing worked.

If i remove the additional_headers and add the Header then the header works and the email i want to be display appears on the inbox.

What is the problem?

Comment: you should read the manual here https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I did but im stupid didnt really understand!

Comment: what do you mean? or have you solved it?

Comment: I solved it just now, thanks :)

Comment: right on, glad to hear it.